# Adding two lists of own type

Tags: java, list, for-loop, arraylist, collections

I have a simple `User` class with a `String` and an `int` property.

I would like to add two Lists of users this way:

- if the String equals then the numbers should be added and that would be its new value.
- The new list should include all users with proper values.

Like this:

```
List1: { [a:2], [b:3] }
List2: { [b:4], [c:5] }
ResultList: {[a:2], [b:7], [c:5]}
```

`User` definition:

```
public class User { 
    private String name;
    private int comments;
}
```

My method:

```
public List<User> addTwoList(List<User> first, List<User> sec) {
    List<User> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0; i<first.size(); i++) {
        Boolean bsin = false;
        Boolean isin = false;
        for (int j=0; j<sec.size(); j++) {
            isin = false; 
            if (first.get(i).getName().equals(sec.get(j).getName())) {
                int value= first.get(i).getComments() + sec.get(j).getComments();
                result.add(new User(first.get(i).getName(), value));
                isin = true;
                bsin = true;
            }
            if (!isin) {result.add(sec.get(j));}
        }
        if (!bsin) {result.add(first.get(i));}
    }
    return result;      
}
```

But it adds a whole lot of things to the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is better done via the `toMap` collector:

```
 Collection<User> result = Stream
    .concat(first.stream(), second.stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        User::getName,
        u -> new User(u.getName(), u.getComments()),
        (l, r) -> {
            l.setComments(l.getComments() + r.getComments());
            return l;
        }))
    .values();
```

- First, concatenate both the lists into a single `Stream<User>` via `Stream.concat`.
- Second, we use the `toMap` collector to merge users that happen to have the same `Name` and get back a result of `Collection<User>`.

if you *strictly* want a `List<User>` then pass the result into the `ArrayList` constructor i.e. `List<User> resultSet = new ArrayList<>(result);`

---

Kudos to @davidxxx, you could collect to a list directly from the pipeline and avoid an intermediate variable creation with:

```
List<User> result = Stream
    .concat(first.stream(), second.stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
         User::getName,
         u -> new User(u.getName(), u.getComments()),
         (l, r) -> {
              l.setComments(l.getComments() + r.getComments());
              return l;
         }))
    .values()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Or why not  `.values().stream().collect(toList())` to avoid defining an additional variable.

Comment: @davidxxx if one doesn't want the creation of a variable then I'd suggest passing the bulk of the pipeline directly to the constructor which leads to less readability to come extent so yes your suggestion is a good point indeed. I'll edit to accommodate.

Comment: Indeed, IntelliJ proposes it. It is crazy :) Your way to collect is straight but the idiom to return the merged object is ugly (not your fault of course) as Java doesn't rely on implicit very much . An immutable approach could make things more readable while may have some consequences on the execution time  : `toMap(User::getName,
u -> new User(u.getName(), u.getComments()),(l, r) -> new User(l.getName(),
l.getComments() + r.getComments()))`

Comment: @davidxxx Indeed, that's another option but I'd stay away from it as you've already hinted it's not memory friendly. a better option would be to extract the merge function to a method inside `User` and then call it with a method reference from the pipeline, that would lead to better readability and avoid the overhead. example the method would look like `public User merge(User other) {
        setComments(getComments() + other.getComments());
        return this;
    }` then use `User::merge` in place of the merge function above.

Comment: @Aomine: Thanks and you are welcome. The biggest issue with [tag:java-stream] is readibility and ability to figure out what a collector exactly needs.

Comment: @Aomnine I understand your POV but note that  the idiom you use to create a new object for each stream element is also not memory/cpu friendly : `-> new User(u.getName(), u.getComments())` Suppose you have 10 elements with the same key on average, it means you create 9 times more objects that necessary.

Comment: @davidxxx in which case, if memory usage is really of concern then I'd consider using `.collect(groupingBy(User::getName, summingInt(User::getComments)))` and then map each entry to a `User` object. ;-)

Comment: It sounds good. And the `groupingBy()` is in this way much more explicit.  I would post something very close yesterday but didn't have the time for.

Comment: @davidxxx yeah, it would be nice if you posted it. @ me when you do so.

Comment: Beyond the memory or cpu usage I find it really neater. The merge function of `toMap()` decreases the readability Similarly to `collectingThen()`. Personally I try to avoid them as much as possible. I posted the answer while you had already given the essential in your comment :)

Answer (score 3):

You have to use an intermediate map to *merge* users from both lists by summing their ages.

One way is with streams, as shown in [Aomine's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54010847/1876620). Here's another way, without streams:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
list1.forEach(u -> map.merge(u.getName(), u.getComments(), Integer::sum));
list2.forEach(u -> map.merge(u.getName(), u.getComments(), Integer::sum));
```

Now, you can create a list of users, as follows:

```
List<User> result = new ArrayList<>();
map.forEach((name, comments) -> result.add(new User(name, comments)));
```

This assumes `User` has a constructor that accepts `name` and `comments`.

---

**EDIT:** As suggested by @davidxxx, we could improve the code by factoring out the first part:

```
BiConsumer<List<User>, Map<String, Integer>> action = (list, map) -> 
        list.forEach(u -> map.merge(u.getName(), u.getComments(), Integer::sum));

Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
action.accept(list1, map);
action.accept(list2, map);
```

This refactor would avoid DRY.

Comment: Nice :) You could factor out the first part : `Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream()).forEach(u->...)`

Comment: @davidxxx I was thinking exactly the same ;) But touching a map from withing `Stream.forEach` is not stream-friendly (it's discouraged in the docs)...

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner: The docs discourage from `Stream::forEach` which is far different from `List::forEach` (or `Iterable::forEach` to be exact) which behaves exactly like the traditional `for-loop`. What do you think? I am not sure.

Comment: @Nikolas what Federico meant was that using `Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream()).forEach(u->...)`  as suggested by david would involve unnecessary side effects as you're then accumulating to a map externally. streams and side effects should not go together. this is even truer when running in parallel. Federico correct me if I am wrong ;-)  but I think that's what you meant.

Comment: @Aomine: I speak about `(list, map) -> list.forEach`. The `stream` is not constructed at all and the `forEach` method causes side-effects - which is fine. Why the `Stream::forEach` is discouraged since it's the same as `Iterable::forEach`? I fully inderstand the side-effect issue with the parallel streams, I don't recommend to use ex. `stream-map-filter-forEach`, however `Stream::forEach` might be fine?.

Comment: @Aomine I meant exactly that :)

Comment: @Nikolas Yes, I think you are correct. There wouldn't be any problem in this specific case. However, I'd rather take this strictly and never use that pattern. It would be just for *stylistic* reasons, if you prefer... Besides, even though it will never happen, you don't know if `Stream.concat` makes the stream parallel or not (it shouldn't, but)...

Comment: That is what I meant, thanks. The `Stream.concat` behavior is new for me, it becomes parallel if one of the inputs is parallel (from the docs). Does it imply that the usage of `Stream.of(...).flatMap(List::stream)...` is safer in this case?

Comment: @Nikolas I don't think so... It's as safe as using `Stream.concat` (which receives 2 streams, and you can control whether both of them are parallel or not), though it has the advantage of letting you *concat* more than 2 collections.

Comment: I like very much the update. Very neat while a little verbose.

Answer (score 2):

There is a pretty direct way using [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) and [`Collectors.reducing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#reducing-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) which **doesnt** require setters, which is the biggest advantage since you can keep the `User` **immutable**:

```
Collection<Optional<User>> d = Stream
    .of(first, second)                    // start with Stream<List<User>> 
    .flatMap(List::stream)                // flatting to the Stream<User>
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(       // Collecting to Map<String, List<User>>
        User::getName,                    // by name (the key)
                                          // and reducing the list into a single User

        Collectors.reducing((l, r) -> new User(l.getName(), l.getComments() + r.getComments()))))
    .values();                            // return values from Map<String, List<User>>
```

Unfortunately, the result is `Collection<Optional<User>>` since the reducing pipeline returns `Optional` since the result might not be present after all. You can stream the values and use the `map()` to get rid of the `Optional` or use `Collectors.collectAndThen`*:

```
Collection<User> d = Stream
    .of(first, second)                    // start with Stream<List<User>> 
    .flatMap(List::stream)                // flatting to the Stream<User>
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(       // Collecting to Map<String, List<User>>       
        User::getName,                    // by name (the key)
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(     // reduce the list into a single User

            Collectors.reducing((l, r) -> new User(l.getName(), l.getComments() + r.getComments())), 
            Optional::get)))              // and extract from the Optional
    .values();
```

<sup>* Thanks to @[Aomine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5862071/aomine)</sup>

Comment: you can pass the `reducing` collector to the `collectingAndThen` collector with `Optional::get` as the finishing function to make things shorter and easier e.g. `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy( 
                        User::getName,                    
                        collectingAndThen(
                                Collectors.reducing((l, r) -> new User(l.getName(), l.getComments() + r.getComments())), Optional::get)))`. this means you don't need the subsequent `.values().stream().....`

Comment: Great! The best on answering questions is the fact I learn more. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

As alternative fairly straight and efficient :

- stream the elements
- collect them into a `Map<String, Integer>` to associate each name to the sum of comments (`int`)
- stream the entries of the collected map to create the List of User.

Alternatively for the third step you could apply a finishing transformation to the `Map` collector with `collectingAndThen(groupingBy()..., m -> ...` 
but I don't find it always very readable and here we could do without.

It would give :

```
List<User> users =
        Stream.concat(first.stream(), second.stream())
              .collect(groupingBy(User::getName, summingInt(User::getComments)))
              .entrySet()
              .stream()
              .map(e -> new User(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
              .collect(toList());
```